# python scipy.optimize curve fitting with only two points

Tags: python

I want to fit power-law model `(x**m * c)` for only two data points to find out the slope `m`. I am using the `curve_fit` function from `scipy.optimize` for this problem. Now when I run the following code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
func = lambda x, m, c: x**m * c
xdata = np.array([235e6, 610e6])
ydata = np.array([0.077, 0.054])
err = np.array([0.0086, 0.0055])
coeff, var = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, sigma=err)
print(coeff, var)
```

It successfully returns the value of `m` i.e. `coeff[0]`. But the value of `var` is `[[ inf  inf] [ inf  inf]]`. Is there any problem because of just two data points? It cannot calculate covariance of best fit parameter values? Then how do I calculate error in `m`?

Answer (score 1):

You have two free parameters and two data points, so the problem is under-constrained. Your fitted curve passes perfectly through the two data points with no error, and so the optimizer cannot calculate a covariance for the parameters.

Comment: It's possible to have a model which fits perfectly through the data points even though it is not under-constrained, this would return an error of `0`. An underconstrained problem returns an error of `inf` as it is not possible to calculate the error.